# R count matched strings

Tags: r

I am trying count matched items between strings:

```
target_str = "a,b,c"
table1 = data.frame(name = c("p1","p2","p3","p4"),
                    str = c("a,b","a","d,e,f","a,a"))
```

Based on `target_str`, count how many matches. I want my output table look like this:

```
name       matches
p1         2        #matches a and b
p2         1        #matches a
p3         0        #no matches
p4         1        #if has duplicate, count only once
```

I have about 1 million `target_str`s that need to calculate the matches, so speed is very important. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want it to treat a string like "a,a" — do you want it to score it as 2 matches or just 1?

Comment: @MichaelVeale "a,a" should only count 1.Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't really understand well the question. The target_str could be instead of "a,b,c" "abc" and the str could be "ab" "a" "def" with the same semantic effect. What is the meaning of putting commas between characters ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis sorry for confusing. I wanted to simplify the string. I am analyzing movie data. In real cases, "a,b,c" could be "Spider Man 1, Spider Man 2, Spider Man 3". Concatenating them together will be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target_str = "a,b,c"
split_str <- strsplit(target_str, split = ",")[[1]]
table1 = data.frame(name = c("p1","p2","p3","p4"),
                    str = c("a,b","a","d,e,f","a,a"))
data.frame(name = table1$name,
           matches = rowSums(sapply(split_str, grepl, x = table1$str)))

#   name matches
# 1   p1       2
# 2   p2       1
# 3   p3       0
# 4   p4       1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly fast:

```
# target string modified to be a character vector:
target_str <- unlist(strsplit(c("a,b,c"), split=","))

# separate each obervations strings:
stringList <- sapply(s, strsplit, split=",")

# get counts, put into data.frame
table1$Counts <- sapply(stringList, function(i) sum(i %in% target_str))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is `s` in `stringList <- sapply(s, strsplit, split=",")`?

Comment: Sure. `strsplit` splits a vector of character strings into a list of vectors where the an element of the list corresponds to the same element of the original vector. The element of the list contains the vector created by splitting the original element. `sapply` moves through each element of the list and runs a function. The function above sums the number of elements contained in your target string.

Answer (score 1):

This cbinds counts to the first column, preserved as a dataframe with drop=FALSE. Counts are added from successive test for "in-ness" with `grepl`:

```
cbind( table1[ ,1,drop=FALSE], counts=rowSums(sapply( scan(text=target_str, sep= ",", what=""),  function(t) { grepl( t, table1$str)})) )
Read 3 items
  name counts
a   p1      2
b   p2      1
c   p3      0
```